# Why is shrinkwrap not applied?

Tags: displacement, shrinkwrap

[`.blend` file](https://pasteall.org/media/0/1/0134dff684a3f405db28694054dbc60e.blend)

Why is the shrinkwrap not applied?

Tutorial: [grow faces over single axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215590/grow-faces-over-single-axis)

From:
[image: from]

To:
[image: to]

Comment: Hello, usually you can just add a comment below the answer if you fail at one point in the explanation. You simply forgot to add the vertex group to the Shell in the Output Vertex Groups in the solidify modifier : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL7zQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit lost with the axis but you can fix it this way:

- In *Object* mode, rotate the vertex 180° on the X axis
- Give your *Solidify* a negative *Thickness* value
- Remove the *Group* from the *Shrinkwrap* modifier (or assign the only vertex to this group)