# vertex based displace - assign random materials to resulting sides -

Tags: displacement

Thanks to @Gorgious for all the expertise in [getting this to where it is](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215598/35559).

I was previously looking to randomly grow faces up from an array of cubes and the best solution for this to use a mix of displacement along array of vertexes that then connect together through screw modifiers followed by solidify and shrinkwrap.

The result was this -

[image]

The mosaic is tied to empty than once moved controls  displacement.

TO achieve the effect below I'm using a colorRamp with constant sliders, but on the offchance I want to mix in different materials, as advised mixed them in using greater than operator and 'Random per island'.
Like this -

[image]
[image]

Question - is it possible to have this apply to individual sides *after* the transform? So that random can select that, from one 'block' the top face and the other ones can be of different colour?

Thanks in advance and again apologies if this is super-newbie, I'm only learning blender but it's looking super exciting (but complicated coming from AE background)

Comment: It's definitely possible, but just so we are on the same page, could you add a schematics or an example of the desired effet ?

Comment: I've followed along and got my fair share of @Gorgious Goodness.. if the _Array_ mods are not applied, I'm already getting all faces of the cubes considered 'islands' from the POV of _Random per Island_. Maybe merging in the arrays merges islands.

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks :) Also a bit of advice if you want random values per face with the Random Per Island output : Use Smooth Shading or an Edge Split modifier and play with the angle value

Comment: hi guys, thanks a lot for your comments. This is 'kind of what I had in mind' - https://imgur.com/HWMiqli but that was back when I thought all I need is to apply displacement and that's job done. Basically at that point I'd assign 5-6 materials then apply to random faces. So in an ideal world I'm looking to combine visuals from that URL with this bouncing mosaic that you helped out with. Promise I'll pass on the knowledge!